# How to get the string from "chrome://downloads" page

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, beautifulsoup

I used `Chromedriver` to download the file, then I would like to parse the `"chrome://downloads"` to get download status, but I can't get the string, please refer to below code and result. I also checked the `HTML` in Chrome. I could saw `<span id="name">Noto-hinted (1).zip</span>`, but if I used the `view page source`, I can't find the string `"Noto-hinted (1).zip"`. It is `<span id="name" hidden="[[completelyOnDisk_]]">[[data.file_name]]</span>`

```
import time, bs4
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://noto-website.storage.googleapis.com/pkgs/Noto-hinted.zip"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
browser.get("chrome://downloads/")
time.sleep(30)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,"lxml")
webElemlist = soup.find('span', id='name')
print(webElemlist)
time.sleep(300)

browser.quit()
```

**Output:**

```
<span id="name"> </span>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
Please edit your code correctly, and read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the downloading item from the screen?
Right-click the element you are trying to click, and select 'Inspect'.
This will open the console and you can see the specific tags for each element of the page, as you hover over them.

I found this for the package:

```
<div id="title-area">
    <a is="action-link" id="file-link" tabindex="0" role="link" hidden="" href="https://noto-website.storage.googleapis.com/pkgs/Noto-hinted.zip">Noto-hinted.zip</a>
    <span id="name">Noto-hinted.zip</span>
    <span id="tag"></span>
</div>
```

All you need to do is get the text for these tags using the IDs. This also applies after you have downloaded the file.

**Edit:**

```
test = """
<div id="title-area">
    <a is="action-link" id="file-link" tabindex="0" role="link" hidden="" href="https://noto-website.storage.googleapis.com/pkgs/Noto-hinted.zip">Noto-hinted.zip</a>
    <span id="name">Noto-hinted.zip</span>
    <span id="tag"></span>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(test, "lxml")

fileDiv = soup.find("span", {"id": "name"}).text

print(fileDiv)
```

If the above does not work, try doing this:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,"html.parser")
```

Comment: Yes, I used right-click and select 'Inspect' to get the id for element, so I use the code 'soup.find('span', id='name')' to find out the element, but I still can't get the string, the string is always empty.

Comment: Have you tried first getting the `div` element using `ID`? That is, `fileDiv = soup.find("div", {"id": "title-area"})` and then search this for the `<span>` element.

Comment: Thanks, I try it, but there is still no string.
fileDiv = soup.find("div", {"id": "title-area"})
print(fileDiv)

output:
<div id="title-area"><a id="file-link" is="action-link"> </a><span id="name"> </span>
<span id="tag"> </span>
</div>

Comment: You code is ok, but I changed test to browser.page_source, I still can't get the string. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I change the 'lxml' to 'html', I got the warning messages as below and still can't get the strings.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python362\lib\site-packages\bs4__init__.py", line 181
    markup_type=markup_type))
UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 1 of the file . To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})

to this:

BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "lxml")

Comment: still can't get the string

<div id="title-area"><a id="file-link" is="action-link"> </a><span id="name"> </span>
<span id="tag"> </span>
</div>